# Why does SQL Server CE not insert some column values?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

First I get some columns values from a `.CSV` file and it works as expected. Next I'm storing the columns data on a matrix, and each row is registered in my database, but, when I query the values, some of them are "".

```
var db = Database.Open("mydb");
int ok = 0; int no = 0;
string[][] r; // Where the results of CSV are stored

for(int i = 0; i < r.Length; i++) {
    string kon = "insert into Data (col1, col2, col3 ...) values (@0, @1, @2 ...)";
    // If data is stored or not
    if(db.Execute(kon, r[i][0], r[i][1], r[i][2], ...)>0){
       ok++;
    }
    else {
       no++;
    }
}
```

So I thought it was my error, but then I tried to execute the query on console and it works correctly. I declared a string, concatenated values and printed it within for loop, and I get some like this:

```
insert into Data (col1, col2, col3 ...) values ("a", "b", "c" ...)
```

When I query all the records on table "Data", values stored by the for loop looks like

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|...
----|----|----|----|...
   a|    |   c|    |...
```

Furthermore, in some records values on col2 and col4 are correct.

When I copy-paste the query on console I got the entire data

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|...
----|----|----|----|...
   a|   b|   c|   d|...
```

I don't understand what it happening, why am I losing the data?

Comment: Are you sure there are all values in the .csv? Have you tried viewing it in excel to check for empty cells?

Comment: Yes, when I print the matrix values at same for loop (r[i][0], r[i][1], r[i][2], ... ), I can see the correct values.

Comment: is this the full loop? How do you set values for `string[][] r;`? I think the trouble is with the `i`.. is it possible you nested it inside the for and now the application is calling the wrong `i`?

Comment: You can also try changing the parameter values to instead of `@0`,`@1`,.... into it's column names (IE `@col1`,`@col2`,...) . see if that works

Comment: are you creating parameters and adding them to your query? Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Well, I resolved it using SQL Server instead SQL Server CE. I tried @Malky.Kid suggestion but data was still lost.

Comment: @CodingYoshi this was my whole code for the insertion, I was using the Database clase on WebMatrix